# User Not in GAL

Tags: active-directory, outlook, exchange-server, gal

I have a user in AD that does not appear in the domains GAL.
This user is in the same security groups and OU as the rest of the users. Nothing seems out of the ordinary. Is there a way to manually have the user appear in the GAL?

Comment: Does that user have a mailbox? Is it hidden?

Comment: The user has a mailbox and the email address appears in the "all user list". This is also not a new user (this is more common with new user, they don't appear in GAL right away). This is a problem that happens also when exchange is upgraded from 2003 (where there are global and local address lists) to 2010 ( where there are global only) so with this deployment all the users from the local list just don't appear any where. But here it's not the case. There was no upgrade and other users that are even older do appear on GAL.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using?  Take a look at the msExchAddressBookPolicyLink attribute and make sure it's pointing to the right Addressbook Policy.